# how to send a email to Opportunity Owner using workflow rule and email alert?

Tags: workflow

how to send a email to Opportunity Owner using workflow rule and email alert ?

Answer (score 1):

Sending email to opportunity owner can be straight forward from the opportunity object.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a condition that will trigger the workflow to happen. Unless there's something that triggers an update or some kind of time-based workflow based on the last time it was updated, there will be nothing to initiated the workflow to cause the email to be sent.

Once you have that condition, you go to:

Setup **>** Create **>** Workflow & Approvals **>** Workflow Rules **>** Click New.

You'll also need to create an email template to use for your email in advance of creating your Workflow rule. Be sure to put it in a public folder.

Just follow the Wizard to create your workflow rule by first selecting your object; in this case Opportunity. Name it and select the criteria you want to use in order to send the email.

Click the Help link for more detailed instructions which should open in a new tab.

Comment: i created workflow rule on aggrement contact object . Active is check box field on aggrement contact   object. when ever Active  check box checked mail trigger to Opportunity Owner . in recipts am not geting oppyowner.

Comment: Is the Opp Owner also the Contract Owner or does that User fit something more like `$User = Contract.ActivatedBy.UserRole.OpportunityAccessForAccountOwner `?